Image works normally on web browser but can't be displayed on coil compose
I have an image url from edamam api with this url Image URL, the image works just fine on browser but can't be displayed using Coil.

That's because in your browser, you are logged in, probably with cookies storing the authentication information.
This is not the case in your app, and therefore something along these lines will be returned instead of the image:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Request has expired</Message>
    <X-Amz-Expires>3600</X-Amz-Expires>
    <Expires>2024-04-23T12:33:15Z</Expires>
    <ServerTime>2024-04-23T12:51:05Z</ServerTime>
    <RequestId>C34YYPA3636TXZQK</RequestId>
    <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>


ah yeah i see, i just tested in incognito mode. Any way i can solve this?

the problem that confused me is the edamam api are doing authentication via API query parameter, and i don't see any thing related to header authentication
